# author2vec angle between vectors notation

Tags: notation, neural-networks

Reading the latest "author2vec" paper ([Author2vec publication](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/262322/jawahar16_www.pdf)), I stumbled upon equations (1):

$h_C^{(x)}=v_u \odot v_p$

and (5): for the sake of this question consider it exactly as (1),

where they use a *point within a circle* ($\odot$) to represent the angle between the embedding vectors.

I'm familiar with the arccos way to get the angle between vectors (solving theta from the dot product definition), but I have never seen this notation to represent it before. I've googled it and found nothing.

Could anyone give some info about this notation? Specifically, if it actually represents the angle between vectors.

Comment: The symbol you are referring to being $\odot$?  TeX command is `\odot`

Comment: Right! What is it refering to?

Comment: According to [this site](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/linear_algebra/vector_vector) is the Element-wise multiplication, which doesn't make any sense since in the paper the output of the operator is a scalar, while the output of the element-wise multiplication is a vector.

Comment: In my experience, no official symbol has been assigned to the operation of finding the angle between two vectors in an arbitrary vector space (beyond the usual $\arccos(\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|u\|\|v\|})$).  Also, $\odot$ is commonly used as a placeholder symbol for operations which are uncommon and are often defined in context.  I expect that this was simply a stylistic choice by the author so that they could use a simpler cleaner notation whenever it came up.  They defined the use of the symbol in the paragraph preceding eqn (1)

Comment: Element-wise multiplication (which is also uncommon and so has competing symbols) I am more used to seeing written as $A\circ B$, also often referred to as the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29).

Comment: Ok, make sense that they used it as a placeholder for the angle between the vectors. Yet, I find a bit hard to get why they didn't use the usual arccos definition instead of the placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JMoravitz stated in the comments, "$\odot$ is commonly used as a placeholder symbol for operations which are uncommon and are often defined in context". In this case, they (authors of the paper) define the operator in the preceding paragraph as the angle between the vectors, so in this context $\odot$ refers to this operation.